# Recursive function in postgres based on query result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to do recursive function in postgres.
As an argument to the fucntion I provide `id`, then I need to query table to get detail information about it. One of columns `parent_id` has a tree structure. Lowwer numer are higher in a tree structure. I would like to ahead higher results in my tree structure.
This is my sql query:

```
create or replace function provide_city_name(id_offer int)
returns int
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
   city_name varchar;
begin
   select id, type, parent_id, name into city_name
   from location
   where id = id_offer;
   if type < 6 then
    return city_name;
   else
    return provide_city_name(parent_id);
   end if;
end;
$$;
```

I got following message:
`':=', <analytic clause>, '=', WITHIN or '[' expected, got ';'`. It occcured in lines with

```
else
provide_city_name(parent_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems with your function:

1. You are trying to return `city_name` which is of type `varchar`. But your function definition declares a return type `int`
2. You cannot put a single column output into a variable this way. The `INTO` clause puts the entire `SELECT` output into the variable, so this must be of type `record` in that case
3. You are fetching the `type` and other columns in your query but they are not stored for further usages. This is why `type` is currently unknown in your `IF` clause. So, here it makes sense, too, to store the output into a `record` variable, which enables you to re-use the value here.

Finally your function could look like this:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=819e6e25f67552cbab5b1f96ee5b9f41)

```
create or replace function provide_city_name(id_offer int)
returns varchar                                       -- change output type
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
   city_record record;                                -- declare record var
begin
   select id, type, parent_id, name 
   into city_record                                   -- put entire record into var
   from location
   where id = id_offer;
   
   if city_record.type < 6 then                       -- check type value of record
    return city_record.name;                          -- return name value of record
   else
    return provide_city_name(city_record.parent_id);  -- recursion with parent_id of record
   end if;
end;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with no need to call function recursively (opening new cursor at each recursive call for each row), but use recursive CTE to get tabular result in batch.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=d039fcc8f17604abf82fb3954fdd91ce)*

> ```
> create function f_get_par_name(p_ids int[])
> returns table(
>   id int,
>   name varchar(100)
> )
> language plpgsql
> as $$
> begin
>
> return query
>
> with recursive rec (id, parent_id, type_, name, lvl, is_leaf, orig_name) as (
>   /*Start the recursion from requested nodes*/
>   select l.id, l.parent_id, l.type_, l.name,
>     0 as lvl,
>     /*The node is leaf if it has no parent or has type = 6*/
>     (l.type_ = 6 or l.parent_id is null) as is_leaf,
>     l.name as orig_name
>   from location as l
>   where l.id = any(p_ids)
>   
>   union all
>   
>   select
>     rec.id,
>     l.parent_id,
>     coalesce(l.type_, rec.type_),
>     coalesce(l.name, rec.name),
>     rec.lvl + 1,
>     (l.type_ = 6 or l.parent_id is null) as is_final,
>     rec.name
>   from rec
>     left join location as l
>       on rec.parent_id = l.id
>         and rec.type_ != 6
>   /*New step is only for nodes which have parent*/
>   where rec.is_leaf = false
>     
> )
> select rec.id, rec.name
> from rec
> where rec.is_leaf = true;
>
> end;
> $$
> ```

With this setup

| id | parent_id | type_ | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1.1 |
| 3 | 2 | 6 | 1.2 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 1.2.1 |
| 5 | 4 | 1 | 1.2.1.1 |
| 6 | 3 | 1 | 1.2.2 |
| 7 | 6 | 6 | 1.2.2.1 |
| 8 | 7 | 1 | 1.2.2.1.1 |
| 9 | 6 | 1 | 1.2.2.2 |
| 10 | 6 | 6 | 1.2.2.3 |

You'll get this:

> ```
> select *
> from f_get_par_name(array[1,3,5,7,9,10])
> order by id asc
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name   
> -: | :------
>  1 | 1      
>  3 | 1.2    
>  5 | 1.2    
>  7 | 1.2.2.1
>  9 | 1.2    
> 10 | 1.2.2.3
> ```